# How to set _id to db document in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to dynamically create _id's for my Mongoose models by counting the documents in the db, and using that number to create the _id (assuming the first _id is 0). However, I can't get the _id to set from my values. Here's my code:

```
//Schemas
var Post = new mongoose.Schema({
    //_id: Number,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    tags: [ String ]
});

var count = 16;

//Models
var PostModel = mongoose.model( 'Post', Post );

app.post( '/', function( request, response ) {

    var post = new PostModel({
        _id: count,
        title: request.body.title,
        content: request.body.content,
        tags: request.body.tags
    });

    post.save( function( err ) {
        if( !err ) {
            return console.log( 'Post saved');
        } else {
            console.log( err );
        }
    });

    count++;

    return response.send(post);
});
```

I've tried to set the _id a number of different ways, but it's not working for me. Here's the latest error:

```
{ message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "16" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  type: 'ObjectId',
  value: 16,
  path: '_id' }
```

If you know what's going on, please let me know.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You either need to declare the `_id` property as part of your schema (you commented it out), or use the `_id` option and set it to `false` (you're using the `id` option, which creates a virtual getter to cast `_id` to a string but still created an `_id` ObjectID property, hence the casting error you get).

So either this:

```
var Post = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Number,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    tags: [ String ]
});
```

Or this:

```
var Post = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String,
    tags: [ String ]
}, { _id: false });
```

Comment: Even after doing this in my db.collection.getIndexes() ` _id : 1` is being shown. Is this correct behavior?

Comment: @SarasArya yes, MongoDB always creates an index for `_id`, regardless of its type (see [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/index-single/#index-type-id)).

Comment: If other Schemes reference your overwritten object don't forget to change it's type also ex, `mongoose.Schema.Types.Number,`. Otherwise `populate` won't work. Wasted hours on this.

Comment: Can i use this on create?

Answer (score 21):

The first piece of @robertklep's code doesn't work for me (mongoose 4), also need to disabled `_id`

```
var Post = new mongoose.Schema({
  _id: Number,
  title: String,
  content: String,
  tags: [ String ]
}, { _id: false });
```

and this works for me

Comment: This option only works for subdocuments, and not standard documents.

Answer (score 6):

Create custom _id in mongoose and save that id as a mongo _id.
Use mongo _id before saving documents like this.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const Post = new mongoose.Schema({
          title: String,
          content: String,
          tags: [ String ]
        }, { _id: false });

// request body to save

let post = new PostModel({
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString(), //5cd5308e695db945d3cc81a9
        title: request.body.title,
        content: request.body.content,
        tags: request.body.tags
    });


post.save();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me when saving new data for the schema. I used the exact code below in my project

```
new User(
    {
      email: thePendingUser.email,
      first_name: first_name || thePendingUser.first_name,
      last_name: last_name || thePendingUser.last_name,
      sdgUser: thePendingUser.sdgUser,
      sdgStatus: "active",
      createdAt: thePendingUser.createdAt,
      _id: thePendingUser._id,
    },
    { _id: thePendingUser._id }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i'm doing. I just added pre save hook that sets _id field.

```
// Hooks
// custom _id schema
modelSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // Only set custom _id if the document is new
  if (this.isNew) {
    this._id = ModelServiceHelpers.getIdKey({ firstPartId: this.userId, secondPartId: this.memberId });
  }
  next();
});
```