# Sharing _ids Mongoose

Tags: mongoose

So, I have two collections that need identifiers unique across them. Using Mongo's advice, I created a third collection of identifiers:

```
const Identifier = Schema(
{
    _id : { type: Buffer, required: true }
});

const FirstCollection = Schema(
{
    identifier: { type: Buffer, ref: "Identifier", required: true }
})

const SecondCollection = Schema(
{
    identifier: { type: Buffer, ref: "Identifier", required: true }
})
```

Then, when they're created I do:

```
var x = new Identifier();
x.save();
new FirstCollection({ identifier: x });
```

So far so good, however, I'm wondering if I can just use this Identifier as the _id itself in the collection:

```
FirstCollection = Schema(
{
   _id: { type: Buffer,
        ref: "Identifier",
        required: true }
})
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry but *"two collections that need identifiers unique across them"*, does that not mean *"the same identifier cannot be used on another document in the other collection"*? If that's your interpretation then that is what the default `ObjectId` value already provides.

Comment: Also, duplicate maybe? [How to set _id to db document in Mongoose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose) Noting all answers and not just the accepted one.