# JSON object mapping to mongoose schema _id

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

Ignore if this has been asked before; I couldn't find it with my keyword searches. Appreciate if someone could give some hints.
Learning mongoose , node js. I have JSON post like below

```
{
 "_id": "711015",  
 "is_in_violation": true, 
 "is_occupied": true,  
 "is_out_of_service": false, 
 "is_reserved": false
}
```

The mongoose schema looks like below:

```
//Create schema and model SlotSchema
const dbSchema = new Schema({
_id:
{
    type: String ,
    required: [true, "Id is required"]
},
is_in_violation: Boolean,
is_occupied: Boolean,
is_out_of_service: Boolean,
is_reserved: Boolean
});
```

In my nodejs app I have post function like below:

```
router.post('/v1/', function (req, res, next)
{   
  var postdata = new SlotSchema(req.body);
  SlotSchema.create(req.body, function (err, postdata) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(postdata);
  });
});
```

All of this works fine. Now noticed that data POST will have id instead of _id. How can I map req.body id to my moongose schema _id. 
Below is JSON which doesn't work:

```
{
  "id": "711015",  
  "is_in_violation": true, 
 "is_occupied": true,  
 "is_out_of_service": false, 
 "is_reserved": false
}
```

Thank you for your time. Cheers

Comment: i think this questation will be helpfull for this problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set \_id to db document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That link gave me some idea thank you @saikat. Below is my solution I ended up with for now.

```
router.post('/v1/', function (req, res, next)
{
  console.log(req.body.id);
  req.body._id = req.body.id; 
  var postdata = new SlotSchema(req.body);
  console.log(postdata);
  SlotSchema.create(postdata, function (err, postdata) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.json(postdata);
  });
});
```

Though this was manual mapping in my opinion. It seems to serve my purpose. I would have wanted to see, if can do automatic mapping from incoming POST to my schema.  Cheers