# Unable to get records by findOne() if I use custom id for inserting records in mongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

So I inserted records in my mongoDB schema using

`> db.records.insert( { _id: "6", "name": "Ashish", "City": "Dallas" } )`

When I am trying to fetch them using http://localhost:6001/api/employees/
I get below response:

```
[{"name":"Chris","City":"New York"},{"name":"Ashish","City":"Dallas"},{"_id":"5a832ac77ffc3c4e149be718","name":"Sarthak","City":"New York"},{"_id":"5a833071e0184c27ff514c6f","number":"6","name":"Ashish","City":"Dallas"}]
```

Notice how certain records have _id field and others do not. The records which do not have _id fields are the ones inserted using `db.records.insert()` command. Also, if I try to fetch those custom entered records, I get error as below:

On trying to fetch records with `_id=6` using http://localhost:6001/api/employees/6 I get :

`{"message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"6\" at path \"_id\" for model \"records\"","name":"CastError","stringValue":"\"6\"","kind":"ObjectId","value":"6","path":"_id"}`

as error response. I am using below code in my app.js to fetch the records:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testing');
var Employee = mongoose.model('records',mongoose.Schema({
    name:String,
    City:String,

}));

var cfenv = require("cfenv");
var appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
var port = appEnv.port || 6016;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/api/employees',function(req,res){
    Employee.find(function(err,employees){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        return res.json(employees);
    });
});

app.get('/api/employees/:id',function(req,res){
    Employee.findOne({_id: req.params.id},function(err,employees){
        if(err)
            return res.send(err);
        return res.json(employees);
    });
});

app.listen(port, function() {   
    console.log('server starting on ' + port);
});
```

Fields in the db as shown in compass tool:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Why are you telling mongo the `_id` of the document?  Let mongo make one for you.  If you don't specify `_id`, it will be a special, unique, identifying value.  See this: [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/).  I'm guessing mongoose will filter the `_id` if it is of `ObjectId` type.

Comment: Actually, I think I may see something wrong.  Try indicating that you do/don't want an `_id` in your schema with `true`/`false`.  See this piece: [Schema option: _id](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#_id).

Comment: But that is actually a requirement. I need to map the documents with the custom ids instead of some arbitrary defined ones. This makes this whole issue.

Comment: So I need to delete my existing `db` schema and create a new one with this option?

Comment: You could also use your own `id` field as apposed to trying to overwrite `_id`.  You can filter off the internal `_id` that mongo tracks in the projection step with `{_id:0}`. See [Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection).

Comment: What about explicitly indicating that `_id` is a Number in your schema as per this answer: [How to set _id to db document in Mongoose?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19761005/691711).

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, but no help. The main issue here is that why I am not able to see `_id` value in my .find response? It just looks like that `_id` is not present for these in the db or it is not able to show it up due to some parsing issue maybe?

Comment: @zero298: I just added the screenshot of what my db shows. Notice that it does contain `_id` fields for all of those records but doesn't show them up in the api call.

Comment: Maybe you are confusing the mongoose API, or maybe even MongoDB itself, as it tries to reach all `_id` values as `ObjectId` and it fails when trying to fetch others.

Comment: @fingeron: Might be possible. But there has to be some way in either of them to get records by my custom ids, right? And most of all, render them on the response if they are in fact present in the db as shown.

Comment: From my experience with mongoose, when fetching items, it actually treats the `_id` field as `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`, in the code as well. I feel confident to assume it tried implementing the same process to the other values you have given. A good way to test this would be to manually set one of those objects' id to a legit MongoDB ID and then see if it fetches that one aswell.

Comment: @fingeron: let me try it out actually.

Comment: @fingeron: same issue. I inserted this record: `> db.records.insert( { _id: "56jjfj", "name": "Paul", "City": "Miami" } )` and when I viewed all of them, it fetched this one as well without any `_id` field in response. And on doing `findOne()` call, same error again.

Comment: I think the issue narrows down to : How can I explicitly convert my custom_id to ObjectId while inserting a record?

Comment: `_id: "56jjfj"` is not a legit mongoDB id. Try inserting one without the `_id` field, so mongoDB will make it's own, and see if it fetches that one.

The way you can do it anyway, is mention it in the schema, and mention what type to treat it as. I think mongoose has a type for more general objects, but you can probably be safe with `String`.

Comment: @fingeron: It does fetch the record with legit mongo id as stated in OP. Its only the custom generated ones which are a issue here.

Comment: Unless you wanna dive into the `mongoose` library source code, mention `_id` in the schema as whatever type you would like to treat it as. Probably be safest with `String`.

Comment: @fingeron: So i added `_id:String,` field in my schema object. I can now see the id's in response. And also I can get the results for findOne() as well. I think all keys have to be treated this way! Thanks for your suggestion! Please mention this as the answer and I shall accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mongoose` library is by default attempting to convert all `_id` values into `mongoose.Types.ObjectId`. It appears to ignore the value if conversion fails. In your situation, what you can probably be safest with is define to `mongoose` how to treat the `_id` fields in the schema.

```
var Employee = mongoose.model('records',mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    name:String,
    City:String,

}));
```