# Mongo generate id from other fields in document

Tags: mongodb

I want my id field to be generated from 2 other fields of my document.
It is possible to do the same in mongo?

For example here is my document:

```
{
        "field1" : "abc",
        "field2" : "xia",
        "field3" : "asd",
        "field4" : "asda"
}
```

I want my `_id` to be `field1 + field2` always , how do I configure same in mongo?

Comment: Pass `_id: field1 + filed2` in your object while saving it to a database. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose

Comment: what if someone updates field1 from console but forgets to change _id .. that is why I wanted to enforce this at db level

Comment: you can't change _id value in mongo. a new ID would mean a new document.