# how to update one table with the _id from another table in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I exported data from a MySQL database into JSON and imported it into MongoDB.  The problem:

When I imported clients, MongoDB created its own _id field (I know this is built in functionality, but MySQL used a clientID, autoincrementing integer).

SO, when I imported my appointments collection, the clientID was renamed oldClientID.  I'd like the clientID field to be the ObjectID of the corresponding client.

My schemas:

```
const apptSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ID: Number,
  clientID: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client'
  },
  oldClientID: Number,
  ...other field data
});

const clientSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 ID: Number,
 familyID: Number,
 first: String,
 last: String,
});
```

Sample Patient Data:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d82240f7c8ddd03b62aee6a"), 
    "ID" : 18, 
    "familyID" : 6,
    "first" : "Jane", 
    "last" : "Doe"
}
```

Sample Appointment Data

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d82c8b95627367d122087f9"), 
    "ID" : 1885, 
    "oldPatientID" : 18, 
    "scheduled" : ISODate("2015-08-05T11:20:00Z"), 
    "note" : ""
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d82c8b95627367d122088a8"), 
    "ID" : 2066, 
    "oldPatientID" : 18,  
    "scheduled" : ISODate("2015-09-17T16:00:00Z"), 
    "note" : ""
}
```

What appointments should look like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d82c8b95627367d122087f9"), 
    "ID" : 1885,
    "clientID": ObjectId("5d82240f7c8ddd03b62aee6a"),
    "oldPatientID" : 18, 
    "scheduled" : ISODate("2015-08-05T11:20:00Z"), 
    "note" : ""
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d82c8b95627367d122088a8"), 
    "ID" : 2066,
    "clientID" : ObjectId("5d82240f7c8ddd03b62aee6a"),
    "oldPatientID" : 18,  
    "scheduled" : ISODate("2015-09-17T16:00:00Z"), 
    "note" : ""
}
```

I am open to learning how to achieve this in the mongo shell or using mongoose in express (or if there is another cool way, like in Robo3T).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB will always use `_id` as the *primary key*, this behavior cannot be overwritten, though you can use the `_id` with values from your custom id. Though this might be confusing, it is better to use indexing on your custom id, and you don't need to use `ObjectId` for the custom index field, but can use your own custom id schema, like `UUID` or an incrementing integer value etc. though it has to be generated/incremented by you or some framework, like `JPA`

Check [Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/)

---

For Mongoose, you can do;

```
new mongoose.Schema({
  customId: { type: Number, index: true }
  ...other field data
});
```

with [`index: true`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes)

Comment: OH!  I didn't know I could do that.  I ended up using an aggregation query with a lookup stage, and then projected the _id from the table into the clientID field.  saved it as a new table and it's connected the mongo way.  Thank you though!  I love this idea!

Comment: @mcadio I see, but you can still pass your custom fields as `_id` in default schema create step with [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose), but normally `_id` is ignored, and a custom field is used with an index

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this worked out for me, although I'm sure there has to be an easier way:

```
db.getCollection("appts").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "clients", 
                "localField" : "clientID", 
                "foreignField" : "ID", 
                "as" : "CLIENT"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "appttypes", 
                "localField" : "type", 
                "foreignField" : "ID", 
                "as" : "TYPE"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "apptstatuses", 
                "localField" : "status", 
                "foreignField" : "ID", 
                "as" : "STATUS"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "_id" : "$_id", 
                "clientID" : "$CLIENT._id", 
                "scheduled" : "$scheduled", 
                "note" : "$note",
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$out" : "apptslinked"
        }
    ]
);
```

Then I exported that as JSON, dropped the appts table, and did a mongoimport using that file.