# creating new field doesn't want to save mongoose.Types.ObjectId as a column in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to link two tables in mongo db. I have a User table where user has an _id. And a News table where the columns should be _id(for the news) and the userId (to link news to a user).

The way my api works, is the userID gets appended to req variable when the request goes through authentication.

This is the model for User

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model(
  "User",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    admin: Boolean,
    profileImage: String,
  })
);
```

And this is a model for News

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const News = mongoose.model(
  "News",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  })
);
```

and this is the snippet for saving a new news record:

```js
upload = (req, res) => {
const news = new News({
    userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId)
})

//at this point userID in news is UNDEFINED for some reason. req.userId is not undefined.
news.save((err)=>{
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: err + "NewsError" });
        return;
      }

})
}
```

Ideally this should end with a new row appearing in the table in the database, but only the auto generated _id appears, and no userID
[No UserID column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezTiB.png)

Comment: Have a look at how a similar question is solved https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760829/how-to-set-id-to-db-document-in-mongoose

Comment: You need to make sure you override the default _id

Comment: @JEFFRINJACOB, I do not need to override the default _id. I still need them to be automatically generated, so that news id has a corresponding userId

Comment: is req.userId is a proper objectid?

Comment: @SmritiShikha, hmm no. Its just a string with the ID, but I have used such a string before casted with mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId) to object.findOne(). and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error:),
Where I define the model. userID is spelled with capital ID, but where I assign the variable its written as userId. I am just blind. Thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of `mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId)` you can instead use this code:

```
const { ObjectId } = require('mongodb');

userId: ObjectId(req.userId);
```

Comment: No that ends up in the same issue :(